How to set the Unbound server as AdGuard DNS ruwithing the same Docker network
I have following compose to run AdGuard and Unbound. Though unbound is accessible using the same host name since both in the same network, AdGuard DNS requires IP of the server(?). How can I set Unbound IP?
  adguardhome:
    image: adguard/adguardhome
    container_name: adguardhome
    restart: unless-stopped
    links:
      - unbound
    volumes:
      - ./data/adguardhome/workdir:/opt/adguardhome/work
      - ./data/adguardhome/confdir:/opt/adguardhome/conf
    ports:
      - 53:53/tcp
      - 53:53/udp
      - 67:67/udp
      - 68:68/udp
      - 80:80/tcp
      - 443:443/tcp
      - 443:443/udp
      - 3000:3000/tcp
      - 853:853/tcp
      - 784:784/udp
      - 853:853/udp
      - 8853:8853/udp
      - 5443:5443/tcp
      - 5443:5443/udp
  unbound:
    image: madnuttah/unbound
    container_name: unbound
    restart: unless-stopped

